# Find in one column & Replace with data from 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to replace both columns A & B in the "Data" sheet with corresponding entry in the "list" sheet.

I have a sheet with hundreds of names listed in *datasheet*'s column B.
I would like to replace these names with the names listed in *listsheet*, which consists of three columns:
`name`, `ID`, `full name`

Name is in both sheets identical. In the code below I replace *name* with *full name*, but i'd like to also add the ID.

[image: Excel preview of the expected result]

```vb
Sub myReplace()

        Dim myDataSheet As Worksheet
        Dim myReplaceSheet As Worksheet
        Dim myLastRow As Long
        Dim myRow As Long
        Dim myFind As String
        Dim myReplace As String

    '   Specify name of Data sheet
        Set myDataSheet = Sheets("Wedstr")

    '   Specify name of Sheet with list of replacements
        Set myReplaceSheet = Sheets("List")

    '   Assuming list of replacement start in column A on row 2, find last entry in list
        myLastRow = myReplaceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '   Loop through all list of replacments
        For myRow = 2 To myLastRow
    '       Get find and replace values (from columns A and B)
            myFind = myReplaceSheet.Cells(myRow, "A")
            myReplace = myReplaceSheet.Cells(myRow, "B")
    '       Start at top of data sheet and do replacements
            myDataSheet.Activate
            Range("A1").Select
    '       Ignore errors that result from finding no matches
            On Error Resume Next
    '       Do all replacements on column A of data sheet
            With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Columns("B").Replace What:=myFind, Replacement:=myReplace, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=True
            Columns("D").Replace What:=myFind, Replacement:=myReplace, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=True

    '       Reset error checking
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next myRow

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        MsgBox "Replacements complete!"

    End Sub
```

Comment: You are receiving down-votes because this question is incredibly vague and broad. You will need to show your code and specify what your specific problem is. Here is a link on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question a little more? What does your workbook look like, how is the data in the sheets stored? Maybe post a screenshot? Do you already have bits of code we may improve?

Comment: Sorry, had some problems to post the question.

Comment: Have you tried just a simple VLOOKUP, inside the sheet, before writing VBA code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do this.

```
Dim myDataSheet As Worksheet
Dim myReplaceSheet As Worksheet
Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim myRow As Long

Dim namedict As Object
Dim namearr(1) As Variant
Dim name As String

Set namedict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set myDataSheet = Sheets("Wedstr")
Set myReplaceSheet = Sheets("List")

myLastRow = myReplaceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
with myreplacesheet
    For myRow = 2 To myLastRow 
        name = .cells(myrow, "A").value
        if not namedict.exists(name) then 'Make sure it doesn't error out if duplicates exist
            namearr(0) = .cells(myrow, "B").value
            namearr(1) = .cells(myrow, "C").value
            namedict.add name, namearr
        end if
     next
end with

with mydatasheet
     mylastrow = .cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row
     for myrow = 2 to mylastrow
         name = .cells(myrow, "A").value
         if namedict.exists(name) then 'Make sure name is in dictionary
             .cells(myrow, "A").value = namedict(name)(0)
             .cells(myrow, "B").value = namedict(name)(1)
         end if
     next
end with
```

I'm not sure if I have your columns correct so watch for that.

If you want to keep your current setup you could take a look at the Range.Resize property. Here are the Docs for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize

Comment: Works perfect. This is what I was looking for. Thank you.